# MySQL : 3 values from 2 tables display 9 rows not 3

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I ran a simple query to display 3 integer values from 2 tables I created. The code as follows:

```
CREATE table T1(
id int
);
CREATE table T2(
id int
);
INSERT into T1 values (1),(2),(3);
INSERT into T2 values (2),(3),(4);
SELECT * FROM t1,t2;
```

The result I want is

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

But It displays

```
3   2
2   2
1   2
3   3
2   3
1   3
3   4
2   4
1   4
```

Also when I run

```
SELECT * FROM T1;
SELECT * FROM T2;
```

It only runs the last SELECT query. i.e. shows values only from T2.

Comment: What's the logic behind the desired result?

Comment: @Strawberry I want to display the results of both tables just once, not like the combination of values it displays

Comment: So 1 > 3, 2 > 2, and 3 > 4 is an equally valid output?

Comment: `from t1, t2` means cartesian product of two sets, so how DBMS should know your intent? And relational tables have no order, you need to specify the ordering you need with `order by` (for join of two ordered sets by ordinal position you need to generate this position with `row_number()`). Anyway please describe the logic behind your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Rows of two tables side by side when ordered by id.

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id
FROM (
    SELECT *, row_number() over(order by id) rn
    FROM T1) t1
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT *, row_number() over(order by id) rn
    FROM T2) t2 ON t1.rn = t2.rn
ORDER BY coalesce(t1.rn, t2.rn);
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can do this using `union all` and `group by`:

```
select max(id1) as id1, max(id2) as id2
from ((select id as id1, null as id2, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select null, id, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
       from t2
      )
     ) t12
group by seqnum;
```

Note that this approach works even when the two tables have different numbers of rows.